# What's the cheapest query I can run to see if there are any rows in the table?

Tags: t-sql

I've been using the `sp_MSforeachtable` built-in stored procedure to determine the row count of each table in our database, using COUNT(*).

I've realized, though, that I just want a 0 or 1, depending on whether there are any rows at all in the table.

Is there something else I can use that's faster/cheaper than COUNT(*)?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597442/subquery-using-exists-1-or-exists

Comment: Whatever answers you come up with should be benchmarked. COUNT(*) is probably well optimized depending on the DBMS, in addition it clearly expresses the intent of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this query. `EXISTS` will stop execution when it finds the first match.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable)
BEGIN
   print 'at least one!'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   print 'no rows found in table'
END
```

Comment: @Downvoter: explain why this doesn't solve the problem and/or help the OP?

Answer (score 3):

This will print all the table names that have at least 1 row

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'if  exists (select 1 from ?) print ''?'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just grab the first row, and display a 1?

`select top 1 1 from tablename`

Comment: @p.campbell: you could just ask for the correction, instead of spending your own rep on downvoting.  :)  Correction look right?

Comment: @p.campbell; gave you an upvote anyways, hopefully that makes up for it.

Comment: actually I didn't downvote your answer! I agree with not wasting rep! But other definitely are downvoting my own!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TABLE
```

Then you can do an EOF check when the recordset is returned.

Answer (score 0):

[`sp_spaceused`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) will probably be more efficient than `COUNT(*)`.

Keep in mind that it does not update in real time so it may not be 100% accurate in all cases.