# Check if value in column for all rows is exactly value

Tags: sql

For example, I want follow the number 2 as target

This should return positive indication:

```
ID       Status
123      2
432      2
531      2
123      2
```

This should return negative indication:

```
ID       Status
123      1
432      3
531      2
123      2
```

This should return negative indication:

```
ID       Status
123      1
432      1
531      1
123      1
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know if all the values are the same or if they are all exactly 2 (for example)?

Comment: What is the data type of the status column?  And what is the database?

Answer (score 18):

`EXISTS` should be used in preference to `COUNT` so it can return as soon as the first non matching row is found.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                         FROM   your_table
                         WHERE  status <> 2) THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
       END AS your_result
```

You don't state RDBMS. You might need to append `FROM DUAL` onto the end of the above dependant on flavour.

Comment: `SELECT *` can be changed to something like `SELECT 1` as improvement

Comment: @demo that isn't an improvement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597442/subquery-using-exists-1-or-exists

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thx

Answer (score 5):

`select count(*) where Status != 2`

Answer (score 5):

```
select (select count(distinct status) from T)  = 1
```

will return 1 or 0 (i.e. true or false) depending on whether all of the rows have the same value in Status or not. If you have to deal with NULL values in status:

```
select exists 
( select status from T where status <> 2 or status is null)
as StatusContainsOtherThanTwoOrNullValue
```