# Check if column value in query is the same in every row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking to be able to see if the value for a column is the same throughout a collection of rows, based on the value of the first row in SQL.

Currently I'm using the following query based on the answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449134/check-if-value-in-column-for-all-rows-is-exactly-value).

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM dbo.Table
        WHERE colA = 'valueA'
        AND colD <> (
            SELECT TOP 1 colD
            FROM dbo.Table
            WHERE LTRIM(colA) = 'valueA'
            AND colB = 'valueB'
            AND (
                colC = 'valueC1'
                OR colC = 'valueC2'
                ... OR colC = 'valueCn'
            )
        )
        AND colB = 'valueB'
        AND (
            colC = 'valueC1'
            OR colC = 'valueC2'
            ... OR colC = 'valueCn'
        )
    ) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS my_result
```

As far as I've been able to test so far, this works, but I've only used a few test cases.  It's also not very scalable, which could be a problem since `colC` could potentially have hundreds of values.

Is there another command or method to handle this better within SQL, or perhaps would it be better to pull the inner `SELECT` statement into it's own query, and then take the result and add it to the outer `SELECT` statement in another resulting query?  Or, am I going about this all wrong to begin with?

This is in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3, which I've added as a tag.  I'm looking for a statement that will preferably return some sort of boolean value that I can evaluate on, similar to how this statement currently returns either `Y` or `N`.  However, if there's a better solution that requires a different output, I can most likely adjust to deal with that.  I'm more concerned in having a good, scalable solution.

Used_By_Already has a good start, however I'm not going to know what the data is ahead of time, so I need a purely dynamic solution.

The planned use case for this is to feed in a single value for `colA` and `colB`, and n values for `colC`, the structure always being `colA AND colB AND (colC1 OR colC2 OR...colCn)`.  These values are being used to retrieve the first datetime from `colD` that is then checked against every value in `colD`, again filtering by the criteria in the first query.  I won't know the value of the datetime in `colD` until the first query is done.

The only information I have ahead of time before going into this query, is `colA`, `colB`, and each value of `colC`.  `colC` will always have at least one value, but could potentially have hundreds of values.  I'm needing to check if every instance filtered by my `WHERE` statement was recorded in the system at the same datetime object, or if they were different.  I don't know what that datetime is, and in all honesty, it's irrelevant **when** it happened, so long as each time it happened is the **same**.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57052/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Example
    ([colA] nvarchar(20), [colB] nchar(1), [colC] smallint, [colD] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Example
    ([colA], [colB], [colC], [colD])
VALUES
    ('123610', 'S', '1', '2017-06-17 11:53:52'),
    ('123610', 'S', '2', '2017-06-17 11:53:52'),
    ('123610', 'R', '3', '2017-06-17 11:53:52'),
    ('123610', 'S', '4', '2017-06-17 11:53:52'),
    ('123611', 'S', '1', '2017-06-17 11:53:52'),
    ('123610', 'S', '5', '2017-06-14 11:53:52'),
    ('123610', 'S', '3', '2017-06-17 11:53:52'),
    ('123610', 'S', '7', '2017-06-15 11:53:52'),
    ('123610', 'S', '8', '2017-06-17 11:53:52'),
    ('123610', 'S', '9', '2017-06-17 11:53:52')
;
```

Query 1

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM Example
        WHERE colA = '123610'
        AND colD <> (
            SELECT TOP 1 colD
            FROM Example
            WHERE colA = '123610'
            AND colB = 'S'
            AND (
                colC = '1'
                OR colC = '2'
                OR colC = '7'
                OR colC = '5'
            )
        )
        AND colB = 'S'
        AND (
            colC = '1'
            OR colC = '2'
            OR colC = '7'
            OR colC = '5'
        )
    ) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS my_result
```

[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57052/2/0)

```
|my_result|
|---------|
|    N    |
```

Query 2

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM Example
        WHERE colA = '123610'
        AND colD <> (
            SELECT TOP 1 colD
            FROM Example
            WHERE colA = '123610'
            AND colB = 'S'
            AND (
                colC = '1'
                OR colC = '2'
                OR colC = '3'
                OR colC = '8'
            )
        )
        AND colB = 'S'
        AND (
            colC = '1'
            OR colC = '2'
            OR colC = '3'
            OR colC = '8'
        )
    ) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS my_result
```

[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57052/2/1)

```
|my_result|
|---------|
|    Y    |
```

Query 3

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM Example
        WHERE colA = '123610'
        AND colD <> (
            SELECT TOP 1 colD
            FROM Example
            WHERE colA = '123610'
            AND colB = 'S'
            AND (
                colC = '1'
                OR colC = '4'
                OR colC = '3'
                OR colC = '8'
            )
        )
        AND colB = 'S'
        AND (
            colC = '1'
            OR colC = '4'
            OR colC = '3'
            OR colC = '8'
        )
    ) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS my_result
```

[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57052/2/2)

```
|my_result|
|---------|
|    N    |
```

Comment: What version of SQL-Server? Also, an example of current output and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show an example of a table with columns A through D and values in each column which you expect to return Y and another table with rows you expect to return N?

Comment: Example of sample data and expected results will help to answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing sample data from that similar question I setup the following:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/849c90/1)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] varchar(4), [Status] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Status])
VALUES
    ('y123', 2),
    ('y432', 2),
    ('y531', 2),
    ('y123', 2),
    ('n123', 1),
    ('n432', 3),
    ('n531', 2),
    ('n123', 2)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
  coalesce(
            (select 'Y' as yn
              from (
                select count(distinct [Status]) yn
                from table1
                where id like 'y%'                 -- data for yes
                having count(distinct [Status]) = 1
                ) as yn)
          ,'N')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/849c90/1/0)**:

```
|   |
|---|
| Y |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select 
  coalesce(
            (select 'Y' as yn
              from (
                select count(distinct [Status]) yn
                from table1
                where id like 'n%'                 -- data for no
                having count(distinct [Status]) = 1
                ) as yn)
          ,'N')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/849c90/1/1)**:

```
|   |
|---|
| N |
```

Comment: The main problem with this is that I won't know what the value is ahead of time, outside of it being a datetime.

Comment: So you have a variable that needs to be compared against a set of rows, that variable is datetime. Where is the problem that you perceive? What rows are you comparing to? What will you be using this for? (eg. a trigger, a procedure? ...) don't just respond here. If it helps everyone edit the question.