# how to set a null value to default in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, null

How do I set an empty set or null value to a default value like 1?

So far, I have this statement, but in case I get null values i want to handle that:

```
select case when count(*)=0 
                   then 0 
                 else 1 
                   end OUTPUT 
from TESTTBL 
where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd')||'0000';
```

Comment: Where do you suppose to get null values?

Comment: well what if i have no values for my timestamp criteria? then count would be always 0 right? i'm just thinking in the case if i have no records.

Comment: if there are no records that fit that condition - you'll get empty recordset, not `null`

Comment: ok, then for empty set. How can I set an empty set to a value of 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
                   ( SELECT * 
                     FROM TESTTBL 
                     WHERE timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
                   )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS OUTPUT
FROM dual
```

**EDIT**

Added `FROM dual` as Oracle does not allow `SELECT` without `FROM` clause.

Comment: @ypercube: +1'd, but I vote for changing from `SELECT *` to `SELECT null` and for adding `FROM dual` in the end

Comment: I doubt there is any difference in performance. We could well use `SELECT 1/0` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597442/subquery-using-exists-1-or-exists/1597487#1597487

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean to check for Null value and set as some default, if so

```
select nvl(column_name,'DEFAULT') from TESTBL where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1,   'yyyymmdd')||'0000';
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```
SELECT DECODE(count(*),0,0,
                      1) OUTPUT
   FROM TESTTBL 
   WHERE TIMESTAMP = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'yyyymmdd')||'0000';
```

Use Decode like

```
SELECT supplier_name,
        decode(supplier_id, 10000,  'Google',
                            10001,  'Microsoft'                                
                           'Sony') result
 FROM suppliers;
```

equivalent to

```
IF supplier_id = 10000 THEN
     result := 'Google';

ELSIF supplier_id = 10001 THEN
    result := 'Microsoft';

ELSE
    result := 'Sony';    
END IF;
```

Or Use coalesce

```
SELECT coalesce( address1, address2) result
FROM suppliers;
```

which is equivalent to

```
IF address1 is not null THEN
     result := address1;

ELSIF address2 is not null THEN
    result := address2;

ELSE
    result := null;

END IF;
```