# IF EXISTS in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exists

If we have a `SELECT` statement inside an `IF EXISTS`, does the execution stop as soon as it finds a record in the table? For example:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM  table1  WHERE Name='John' )

return 1

else

return 0
```

If a row exists in the table with the name = John, does it stops execution and returns 1 or does it traverses through the entire table looking for more matches?

Comment: FYI, you might also consider using SELECT 1 instead of SELECT * so that you can take better advantage of indexes (not retrieving all of the fields from the table).

Comment: @sfuqua [This is a myth](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/09/age-old-select-vs-select-1-debate.html)

Comment: IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 / 0 FROM table1 WHERE Name='John') ... this won't error... SQL is never evaluating the `SELECT`... it's just looking at the `WHERE`.

Comment: I use 'SELECT 1' for two reasons. One, the parser does in fact query table metadata to expand the '*' as recently as SQL 2008, leading to a small (negligable) perf hit. The more important reason is to communicate directly in the code that the column list is meaningless.

Comment: @codekaizen - The parser also does this for `SELECT 1` as the graphs and example with "SELECT 1" failing due to column permissions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597442/subquery-using-exists-1-or-exists/6140367#6140367) shows.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes it stops execution so this is generally preferable to `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` which often won't.

With `EXISTS` if you look at the execution plan you will see that the actual number of rows coming out of `table1` will not be more than 1 irrespective of number of matching records.

In some circumstances SQL Server can convert the tree for the `COUNT` query to the same as the one for `EXISTS` during the simplification phase (with a semi join and no aggregate operator in sight) [an example of that is discussed in the comments here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190319012047/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx).

For more complicated sub trees than shown in the question you may occasionally find the `COUNT` performs better than `EXISTS` however. Because the semi join needs only retrieve one row from the sub tree this can encourage a plan with nested loops for that part of the tree - which may not work out optimal in practice.

Comment: Is there a better way to do the following:                         IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE xxx AND yyy) 
        RETURN 2 
ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE xxx) 
              RETURN 1 
            ELSE 
              RETURN 0 
        END                                                                  I have this inside a stored proc and the stored proc gets executed very often. My primary motivation is to improve the performance. I know I can use a constant 1 or 0 instead of a * in SELECT but the corresponding performance improvement is negligible

Comment: @Sidd - Possibly  depending on what the exact query is and what indexes you have. You could instead do `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM t1 WHERE xxx ORDER BY some_condition_that_would_mean_yyyy_would_be_first` then inspect the result.

Answer (score -5):

There's no need for "else" in this case:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM  table1  WHERE Name='John' ) return 1
return 0
```

Comment: A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.