# Select all from table except the records from a file

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

I have a table A with one column named a, and a file "test.txt" contains:

```
111111AAAA
222222BBBB
3333DDDDDD
.....
```

The records in test.txt have the same type with "a" column.
How to select all from A except the records in "test.txt"?

**Update:**
I tried 3 ways and the results not equal. What a strange!

```
// 7073 records -- Using NOT IN
SELECT * from mt_users WHERE TERMINAL_NUMBER_1 NOT IN (SELECT TERMINAL_NUMBER FROM A);

// 7075 records -- Using NOT EXISTS
SELECT * from mt_users WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.TERMINAL_NUMBER = mt_users.TERMINAL_NUMBER_1);

// 7075 records -- Using LEFT JOIN
SELECT * FROM mt_users m LEFT JOIN A a ON m.TERMINAL_NUMBER_1 = a.TERMINAL_NUMBER WHERE a.TERMINAL_NUMBER IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly put all records from file into the `newTable` and make sure that there are no additional spaces at the beginning or the end in each field.

```
select a from tableA t where not exists(select 1 from newTable n where n.a = t.a)
```

Comment: can you explain why select "1" but "*"?

Comment: There is no special reason at all ([exists 1 vs exists *](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1597487/1027198)) I just get used to use it. It looks "nicer" for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Put the records from test.txt into a different table.

**Step 2.**

```
SELECT a from tableA WHERE a NOT EXISTS (SELECT a FROM newTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

doing what aF wrote would be my first answer too. if you cant/do not want to do that try "NOT IN" like:

```
SELECT a FROM A WHERE a NOT IN(...)
```

You have to generate the content of the () in the code where you create your query