# SQL statement doesn't update any rows

Tags: .net, sql-server

EDIT: Ok I figured it out, I have an if statement that must return true in order for the SQL to run, that's the problem. Nothing was wrong with my SQL. Sorry!

I don't know what is wrong with this statement, but it will not UPDATE any row.

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM dtRaces 
  WHERE 
      Date = @date 
  AND Location = @location 
  AND Time = @time
  ) 
  UPDATE dtRaces SET 
    Date=@date, 
    Location=@location, 
    Time=@time
    City=@city, 
    State=@state, 
    Title=@title
  WHERE 
      Date = @date 
  AND Location = @location 
  AND Time = @time 
ELSE 
  INSERT INTO dtRaces (Date, Location, Time, City, State, Title) 
  VALUES (@date, @location, @time, @city, @state, @title)
```

Any ideas? I'm stumped.
This is with SQL Server 2008, but I have not learned how to use MERGE yet.

Comment: Would it insert but not update?

Comment: "If rows exist with these values, update those rows to have the exact same values." You don't see the problem with that?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Yeah, not entirely sure what the OP is trying to do here.  Maybe the UPDATE should update the City, State and Title fields as well, or instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, my original post was edited and improperly changed. It's now fixed to include other values in the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the statement:

```
 UPDATE dtRaces SET 
    Date=@date, 
    Location=@location, 
    Time=@time 
  WHERE 
      Date = @date 
  AND Location = @location 
  AND Time = @time
```

This is updating columns to have values, but only where they already have those values - you'll never see updated data from this.

Comment: I'm sorry, my original post was edited and improperly changed. It's now fixed to include other values in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: EDIT: Ok I figured it out, I have an if statement that must return true in order for the SQL to run, that's the problem. Nothing was wrong with my SQL. Sorry!

Comment: @user1230593: Yes it does have to return true. Having said that the `EXISTS` in your example code should have been ok.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you compare the values.

Start with

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dtRaces WHERE Date = @date AND Location = @location AND Time = @time) 
begin
print('exists')
end
else 
begin
print('insert')
end
```

You could change the print statements to select the information and compare it.

Comment: @OlegDok - The answer does not say that they are logically different, only that there is a very slight performance difference. As far as I recall it may actually be true, for reasons deep inside the engine, there is much discussion on it that can be found on the web. But it is so intangible that it makes *virtually* no *perceptible* difference. I have no idea how you justify a -1 for that. Especially considering it may be technically true.

Comment: I removed that statement about select 1 instead of select * since it seams controversial and it was several years ago since I last tested it.

Comment: @Dems - As far as I know - Sql Server does not consider columns list at all inside EXISTS clause. So - there will no any even tiny and technical performance difference. You can check it by denying access to one of columns to specific user and let this user use SELECT * - there will be no security error, instead if you do simple select * - there will be one\

Comment: @OlegDok - If you are so convinced that you ***know*** the answer, read Martin Smith's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597442/subquery-using-exists-1-or-exists .  An answer that quotes one of the SQL Server team (it makes an extremely minor difference in compilation), and still concludes that no conclusion can be drawn.  In short - It appears that you think you know something categorically, but that you simply can't know it without de-compiling and analyisng SQL Server.  Sorry.

Comment: @Dems Agree - all the things connected to Query Optimizer is a black box and probably highest secret and "know hows". But if this mean that we cannot say something about - no. I read the noticed questions and answer. I understand that in compiletime there can be some difference - but during my tests - there is no such a difference. Even is MS guy says that it is. "Do yourself a favor - trust no one, even do not trust to MS tech staff, test it" (c) They too can be wrong. But even if **I am wrong** with this - the gain will be so negligible (even under the borders of errors in measurements)...

Comment: @Dems ... that it is completely looks like "permature optimization". And sorry for my english.

Comment: I'm sorry, my original post was edited and improperly changed. It's now fixed to include other values in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: EDIT: Ok I figured it out, I have an if statement that must return true in order for the SQL to run, that's the problem. Nothing was wrong with my SQL. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the row to the **same values** if the row is exists. So - it **looks like** nothing happened.

**But** if you create trigger after update - you definitely will see that it runs

PS: Overall behavior is little bit strange.

**Edit:**

Now it looks better, but you still have no needs to update some of values to the same values, see this:

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM dtRaces 
  WHERE 
      Date = @date 
  AND Location = @location 
  AND Time = @time
  ) 
  UPDATE dtRaces SET 
    City=@city, 
    State=@state, 
    Title=@title
  WHERE 
      Date = @date 
  AND Location = @location 
  AND Time = @time 
ELSE 
  INSERT INTO dtRaces (Date, Location, Time, City, State, Title) 
  VALUES (@date, @location, @time, @city, @state, @title)
```

**For using MERGE** you have to guarrantee, that these three columns will always be unique: Date, Time, Location. If so - the MERGE will look like this:

```
MERGE dtRaces T
USING (SELECT 1 S) S 
ON   T.Date = @date AND T.Location = @location AND Time = @time 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
    City=@city, 
    State=@state, 
    Title=@title
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Date, Location, Time, City, State, Title) 
    VALUES (@date, @location, @time, @city, @state, @title);
```

PS: If one of your variables (@Date, @Time, @Location) has the value of `NULL` - you also will never get an update.

Comment: I'm sorry, my original post was edited and improperly changed. It's now fixed to include other values in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: EDIT: Ok I figured it out, I have an if statement that must return true in order for the SQL to run, that's the problem. Nothing was wrong with my SQL. Sorry!

Comment: Updated answer. See the last PS too.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dtRaces SET 
  Date=@date, 
  Location=@location, 
  Time=@time 
WHERE 
  Date = @date 
  AND Location = @location 
  AND Time = @time
```

You are trying to update the values with `@date, @location, @time` and you are trying to find the records with `date=@date,location=@location,time=@time`.

Comment: EDIT: Ok I figured it out, I have an if statement that must return true in order for the SQL to run, that's the problem. Nothing was wrong with my SQL. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, I have an if statement that must return true in order for the SQL to run, that's the problem. Nothing was wrong with my SQL. Sorry!