# Return Boolean Value on SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, select, boolean

How to return a boolean value on SQL Select Statement?

I tried this code:

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT) AS Expr1
FROM [User]
WHERE (UserID = 20070022)
```

And it only returns `TRUE` if the `UserID` exists on the table. I want it to return `FALSE` if the `UserID` doesn't exist on the table.

Comment: Which dbms? Details of sql differ.

Comment: SQL Server does not support a Boolean type e.g. `SELECT WHEN CAST(1 AS BIT) THEN 'YES' END AS result` -- results in an error i.e. `CAST(1 AS BIT)` is not the same logical TRUE.

Answer (score 335, accepted):

What you have there will return no row at all if the user doesn't exist. Here's what you need:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM [User]
    WHERE UserID = 20070022
)
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

Comment: why use asterisk, it is better if you use `1` instead of `*`.

Comment: @robertpeter07 - The two are equivalent, but `*` is more idiomatic. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1597442/1121833).

Comment: If using on a WHILE loop would I have to enclose it within braces {} right after the 'WHILE' ?

Comment: Can you add a column name to the returned value?

Comment: @xMetalDetectorx This worked for me to add the column name (the `AS bool` part is very important): `CAST( CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mytable.id = 1) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS bool) AS nameofmycolumn`

Comment: Really an extremely minor point... but I would put the cast around the case rather than having to cast two expressions.

Answer (score 45):

Possibly something along these lines:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
FROM dummy WHERE id = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e555/1

Comment: This returns a string, not a boolean

Comment: It's a good practice to include a column name - SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) as mycolumnname
FROM dummy WHERE id = 1

Answer (score 28):

Given that commonly `1 = true` and `0 = false`, all you need to do is count the number of rows, and cast to a `boolean`.

Hence, your posted code only needs a `COUNT()` function added:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(1) AS BIT) AS Expr1
FROM [User]
WHERE (UserID = 20070022)
```

Comment: Doing the `Exists(` test is much faster than doing a `Count(1)` test on tables with large numbers of rows.

Comment: Probably. I made no claims to performance in my answer, just the minimal code change to achieve what the OP wanted. However, if column `UserID` is indexed (or is even the PK) surely you're going straight to the one unique row that exists (or not).

Answer (score 19):

Use 'Exists' which returns either 0 or 1.

The query will be like:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE UserID = 20070022)
```

Comment: Error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'."
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef905/18

Comment: Would `SELECT 1` be faster than `SELECT *` in this case?

Answer (score 11):

```
select CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIT) FROM [User] WHERE (UserID = 20070022)
```

If count(*) = 0 returns false. If count(*) > 0 returns true.

Answer (score 7):

I do it like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE UserID = 20070022
```

Seeing as a boolean can never be null (at least in .NET), it should default to false or you can set it to that yourself if it's defaulting true. However 1 = true, so null = false, and no extra syntax.

Note: I use Dapper as my micro orm, I'd imagine ADO should work the same.

Comment: My favorite, most concise answer so far.
Fiddle of all answers: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef905/18

Comment: "Seeing as a boolean can never be null (at least in .NET)."  (bool?) is a nullable bool.

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who are interested in getting the value adding a custom column name, this worked for me:

```
CAST(
    CASE WHEN EXISTS ( 
           SELECT * 
           FROM mytable 
           WHERE mytable.id = 1
    ) 
    THEN TRUE 
    ELSE FALSE 
    END AS bool) 
AS "nameOfMyColumn"
```

You can skip the double quotes from the column name in case you're not interested in keeping the case sensitivity of the name (in some clients).

I slightly tweaked @Chad's answer for this.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Comment: @ShaneC I tested this code on PostgreSQL 9.X and it worked fine. What server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Notice another equivalent problem: Creating an SQL query that returns (1) if the condition is satisfied and an empty result otherwise. Notice that a solution to this problem is more general and can easily be used with the above answers to achieve the question that you asked. Since this problem is more general, I am proving its solution in addition to the beautiful solutions presented above to your problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS Expr1
FROM [User]
WHERE (UserID = 20070022)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @isAvailable      BIT = 0;

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1  FROM [User] WHERE (UserID = 20070022))
BEGIN
 SET @isAvailable = 1
END
```

initially isAvailable boolean value is set to 0