# SQL Insert Into Exists - Adding a foreign key to existing table

Tags: sql, insert, exists

I am trying to add a key from one table to another so that I can create a one to many relationship.  The table I would like to add a foreign key to currently has the employee's first name and last name, but not ID.  I would like to query the employee table to find the ID based on their first name and last name, and then add it to the injury table.

I Keep getting the following errors:

```
The multi-part identifier "InjuryOLD.FirstName" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "dbo.InjuryOLD.LastName" could not be bound.
```

Below is the SQL Statement:

```
Insert into dbo.InjuryOLD(dbo.InjuryOLD.EmpID)
Select dbo.EmployeeInformation.EmpID
From EmployeeInformation
Where exists(select dbo.EmployeeInformation.EmpID from dbo.EmployeeInformation
             where dbo.EmployeeInformation.FirstName = dbo.InjuryOLD.FirstName 
             and dbo.EmployeeInformation.LastName = dbo.InjuryOLD.LastName)
```

I have ensured that the tables and columns that I am referencing have no typo's, and I know that there is a chance that two employee could have the same name.  However that is not the case in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SELECT` part an `INSERT` statement should always work on its own

so...

```
Select dbo.EmployeeInformation.EmpID
From EmployeeInformation
Where exists(select dbo.EmployeeInformation.EmpID from dbo.EmployeeInformation
             where dbo.EmployeeInformation.FirstName = dbo.InjuryOLD.FirstName 
             and dbo.EmployeeInformation.LastName = dbo.InjuryOLD.LastName)
```

...doesn't work because `dbo.InjuryOLD` isn't referenced in either FROM clause. You probably meant to put the `dbo.InjuryOLD` in the from clause of the Exists sub query instead of repeating `EmployeeInformation`

```
Select dbo.EmployeeInformation.EmpID
From EmployeeInformation
Where exists(select 1 from dbo.InjuryOLD  
             where
                 dbo.EmployeeInformation.FirstName = dbo.InjuryOLD.FirstName 
                 and dbo.EmployeeInformation.LastName = dbo.InjuryOLD.LastName)
```

Comment: This runs fine and throws no errors, but it doesn't give me the results I wanted. It returned no values, It is querying the Injury table for ID's and I want to query the employee table for Id's. What does the "Select 1 From" in your statement do? Also perhaps "exists" is not the command I need to use. Would you happen to know?

Comment: Its querying the EmployeeInformation for IDs but only including where it can find a match in the InjuryOld table based on first and last names. WRT `SELECT 1` In an exists statement the [select clause is ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1597442), so I always write `SELECT 1 ` so I don't have to think.

Comment: You were right.  It was returning no results because I had labeled the first and last names backwards in the employee table.  Thanks for the help.