# Is it ok to use SELECT * for doing an existence check in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new in T-SQL. As far as I know, SELECT * is considered to be a bad practice so I always avoid using SELECT * in my code.

However, my colleague told me that use SELECT * is fine for doing an existence check. For example,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tb_test WHERE ResourceType = 2)
BEGIN
    --do something
END
```

"Because the MSSQL Server knows that the statement is doing an existence check, the optimizer will do the right thing." he said.

Is there no performance overhead when I use SELECT * for doing an existence check??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always check the query execution plan and compare. I dont think its going to make much differences between `Select *` and `Select 1` unless its in `If` condition

Comment: I always used to write these as `SELECT 1 FROM...` as well, but when in doubt, check the execution plan.

Comment: @Nilesh No it doesn't. See [Subquery using Exists 1 or Exists \*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597442/subquery-using-exists-1-or-exists). What do you mean by "unless its in `If` condition"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your colleague is correct<sup>1</sup>. The optimizer knows that no column data actually needs to be retrieved.

But you're also correct that, *in general*, `SELECT *` should be avoided. `EXISTS` checks are the exception that proves the rule.

<sup>1</sup>A bit of a rarity on SO in my experience.