# Exists / not exists: 'select 1' vs 'select field'

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, exists

Which one of the two would perform better(I was recently accused of not being careful with my code because I used the later in Oracle):

```
Select * 
from Tab1
Where (not) exists(Select 1 From Tab2 Where Tab1.id = Tab2.id)


Select * 
from Tab1
Where (not) exists(Select Field1 From Tab2 Where Tab1.id = Tab2.id)
```

Or are they both same?

Please answer both from SQL Server perspective as well as Oracle perspective.

I have googled (mostly from sql-server side) and found that there is still a lot of debate over this although my present opinion/assumption is the optimiser in both the RDMBS are mature enough to understand that all that is required from the subquery is a Boolean value.

Comment: No difference, they both are same. Check the execution plan for both queries to verify.

Comment: Take a look at this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/a/6140367/2975396

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. `exists` checks if there is at least one row in the sub query. If so, it evaluates to `true`. The columns in the sub query don't matter in any way.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx), `exists`:

> Specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows.

And [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/conditions012.htm#SQLRF52167):

> An EXISTS condition tests for existence of rows in a subquery.

Maybe the [MySQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) is even more explaining:

> Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. **MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference.**

Comment: Does it make a difference Postgres?

Comment: I don't know. I have no experience with Postegres.

Comment: PostgreSQL is the same. You might as well select null as anything else.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old,but want to add few points i observed recently..

Even though exists checks for only existence ,when we write "select *" all ,columns will be expanded,other than this slight overhead ,there are no differences.

Source:
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/exists-subqueries-select-1-vs-select/

**Update:**
Article i referred seems to be not valid.Even though when we write,`select 1` ,SQLServer will expand all the columns ..

please refer to below link for in depth analysis and performance statistics,when using various approaches..

[Subquery using Exists 1 or Exists *](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6140367/2975396)

Comment: Conor's article there is actually wrong. He suggests that `SELECT *` will expand all column metadata and `SELECT 1` won't. However they both in fact do so.  You can see this by denying permissions on a column and running `SELECT 1 WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   T);`  which can unexpectedly fail with `The SELECT permission was denied on the column 'Foo'` or by simply timing the effect of adding more columns with both or looking in a debugger http://stackoverflow.com/a/6140367/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith:Thanks a lot,i read your answer long back,but some how missed few things.Thanks again for debunking the myth

Answer (score 3):

The expression in the subquery's column list matters absolutely nothing, it will not even be executed:

```
select * from dual t1
where exists (
    select 1/0 from dual t2
         --^^^ division by 0  
    where t2.dummy = t2.dummy)
/

DUMMY
--------
X
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing to watch out for in my experience between using
"EXISTS(SELECT * ..." and "EXISTS(SELECT 1 ..." is that "*" is not allowed in schema-bound objects -- it will throw:

Syntax '*' is not allowed in schema-bound objects.