# SQL Filtering out the data based on wrong correlation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
SELECT   phone,
             effdate,
             enddate
    FROM     my_table table1
    WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM   my_table table2
                     WHERE  table1.phone = table2.phone
                       AND  table1.effdate = table2.effdate
                       AND  table1.enddate <> table2.enddate)
    ORDER BY phone,
             effdate,
             enddate
```

which gives me this data:

```
  Phone        Effdate           End_date
2017937950    10/31/2010       6/30/2011 23:59
2017937950    10/31/2010       4/8/2014 23:59
4054631308    5/9/2008         7/14/2009 23:59
4054631308    5/9/2008         12/31/2099
```

which is ok but when I check it in the table with the phone those are like this:

```
  Phone          Effdate      End_date
2017937950      10/31/2010    6/30/2011 23:59
2017937950      10/31/2010    4/8/2014 23:59
2017937950      5/28/2014     12/31/2099
4054631308      6/15/2005     2/25/2008 23:59
4054631308      5/9/2008      7/14/2009 23:59
4054631308      5/9/2008      12/31/2099
```

But from this data I only need this kind of phone because correlation of Effdate and End_date incorrect 7/14/2009 end_date and 5/9/2008 effdate

```
   Phone        Effdate       End_date
 4054631308     5/9/2008      7/14/2009 23:59
 4054631308     5/9/2008      12/31/2099
```

because phone number like 2017937950 has eff_date and end_date is right.

```
    Phone       Effdate       End_date
 2017937950     10/31/2010    4/8/2014 23:59
 2017937950     5/28/2014     12/31/2099
```

If you see this it looks correlation of Effdate and End_date is correct 4/8/2014 end_date and 5/28/2014 Effdate.

I am using above big query to filter out when Phone and Effdate is same and End_date is different give that data above BUT now I am not sure how to filter out those most eff_date and end_date which correlations are correct.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is defined as correlations being correct?  Just that End Date of one is less than Start Date of the Other?  Or do you only want to find rows where the start date is the same but end dates are different?  I'm confused because it seems like you would want the first two rows of your data to show up as well as these look wrong (the 2017937950       with two same start dates??)

Comment: Firstly, change "select *" to "select 1".  This acts as a cut operator so it stops on the first true and doesn't assemble a large record set.

Comment: @T Gray: You're going to need to back up that claim, because afaik, that's not true.  It makes no difference.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461868/exists-not-exists-select-1-vs-select-field) for more info.

Comment: @EoinS
Whenever the next eff_date of the same phone is greater than the End_date then that phone's correlation of eff_date and end_date is correct. Such as 2017937950.
If the next eff_date of the same phone is less than the end_date or same as last eff_date then that correlation is incorrect. For example 4054631308.
I need to pick only wrong correlation data.

Comment: @TGray: that claim is completely wrong and has never been true. There is absolutely no difference in performance or behaviour between `select *` or `select 1` in a sub-query used for the `exists` operator. You could even use `select null` in there if you wanted. Because the _value_ returned by that subquery **completely** irrelevant