# EXISTS subquery: SELECT 1 or SELECT * FROM X performant in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, exists

Is it better (in terms of performance, speed, etc.) to write

`SELECT * FROM a WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b))`

or

`SELECT * FROM a WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b))`

in PostgreSQL?

p.s. 
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26461868/590767) answers my question for MS SQL Server, but what about PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html):

> Since the result depends only on whether any rows are returned, and
>   not on the contents of those rows, the output list of the subquery is
>   normally unimportant.

Comment: What does `unimportant` mean. They're obviously semantically the same but want I wish to know is whether one is more performant than the other (and I'm not sure how to go about testing this out)

Comment: In the context of *The subquery will generally only be executed long enough to determine whether at least one row is returned, not all the way to completion* (for the documentation) I understand there is no difference. You can test it with `explain analyse` - i've got exactly the same executing plans.