# SQL Query Optimization, looking at first x number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query works, but is there a better way to write this query?  The current one seems slow.  The scenario is very straight forward.

I have two tables, Customers and Payments.  The Customers table has what you would expect with Customer info.  The Payments table keeps track of the monthly payments that a Customer makes.  It has a few fields we need to look at - DueDate, PaymentDate, and CustomerID.

The query I want is I want all Customers who were late by at least 3 months in their first 12 payments.  The query I have is below, but it seems to be pretty slow.  Is there a better way to write this, than what I have below?

```
SELECT  CustomerID
FROM    Customers AS C
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT DueDate, CustomerID, PaymentDate
                 FROM   ( SELECT TOP 12 *
                          FROM      Payments as P
                          WHERE     P.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
                          ORDER BY PaymentDate
                        ) AS First12Payments
                 WHERE  DATEDIFF(MONTH, First12Payments.DueDate, First12Payments.PaymentDate) > 3 )
```

Thanks!

Comment: One easy optimization would be to add a new "MonthsLate" column on the payments table, which is pre-computed. Then you could filter directly on that column rather than on a computation.

Comment: @JoeEnos Which would fly if you then indexed the MonthsLate column.  It could even be a filtered index `where MonthsLate is not null` so that customers who never pay late won't result in the maintenance overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the suggestions in the comment by Joe Enos and Brandon are great. However, if you can't add that column there 2 minor changes to your SQL statement that will probably make it a little bit faster. to make it better you will probably need to add indexes to columns DueDate and PaymentDate in Payments table.

```
SELECT  CustomerID
FROM    Customers AS C
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1 -- no need for a columns list since you only check for existance
    FROM (SELECT TOP 12 DueDate, PaymentDate -- no need for all the columns, only the ones you use
          FROM      Payments as P
          WHERE     P.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
          ORDER BY PaymentDate
         ) AS First12Payments
        WHERE  DATEDIFF(MONTH, First12Payments.DueDate, First12Payments.PaymentDate) > 3
```

Comment: `SELECT 1` instead of selecting columns in the exists, although nicer to look at, won't affect performance. SQL Server is smart and knows it's being used for an `EXISTS` and doesn't actually return any data. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1597487/1630665. Minimizing the columns for the inner select should help, though.

Comment: @DaveZych Thanks, I didn't know that. it's an advice I've got from a DBA a few years ago, I guess Microsoft has improved SQL Server since then :-)

Comment: Thanks @DaveZych and Zohar, I did not know that about the EXISTS keyword either.  The 1/0 thing in the example is pretty awesome.