# postgres: why `select null` in subquery?

Tags: postgresql

Two tables in myschema: post and comment. comment's onId refers to post's is. Among the following two pieces of postgres codes, why `select null` in the first piece of codes? what are the differences?

```
DELETE FROM myschema.comment comment
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM myschema.post post
    WHERE post.id = comment."onId"
  );

DELETE FROM myschema.comment comment
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM myschema.post post
    WHERE post.id = comment."onId"
  );
```

Can anyone give some examples to show the differences? Thanks

(postgres is not same with mysql. so my question is not duplicated. I can not tag my question with `mysql`, and I always will not search questions tagged with `mysql`. That is why I put `postgres` in my post title.)

Comment: In addition - in functionallity ? they're the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subquery using Exists 1 or Exists \*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597442/subquery-using-exists-1-or-exists)

Comment: @DaveNewton in this context - none retireve data?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Hm, yeah, looks like they ask just optimize it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres is smart enough to ignore the select statement for `exists` subqueries, so it doesn't make any difference whether you select `null`, `1`, or `*`.

See [Subquery using Exists 1 or Exists *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597442/subquery-using-exists-1-or-exists). That question is related to sql-server but the same applies to postgres

Comment: postgres is not same with mysql. so my question is not duplicated. I can not tag my question with `mysql`, and I always will not search questions tagged with `mysql`. That is why I put `postgres` in my post title.

Comment: It does not matter much about the dbms vendor here. The standard behaviour for [NOT] EXISTS subqueries is that the select clause isn't important and really only  used in these c ircumstances because the SQL standard requires a select clause. Internally these predicates are treated as semi-joins and the from and where clauses of those subqueries are the important parts of them. Select *, select 1, select null, are covention preferences.